# Option should leads to URL only when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have made a dropdown form with two options, each lead to different URL. I want the selected option lead to its 'URL' ONLY when the submit button is clicked.
I have used the following JS code:

```
function handleFormSubmit() {
 var form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var destination = document.getElementById("destination");
location = destination.options[destination.selectedIndex].value;
});
}
```

Now, when I click the submit button, it does not navigate to the url specified in `value` attribute of `option`. (Nothing happens.)

Following is the HTML of my form:

```
`<form action="" method="post">
  <label for="destination">Travelling to:</label>
  <select id="destination" name="destination">
    <option value="https://nstcprep.blogspot.com/">Destination 1</option>
    <option value="https://nstcprep.blogspot.com/">Destination 2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>`
```

Comment: You need to set `window.location`, not just `location`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the below code in your file.

```js
function link() {
            var dropDownVal = document.getElementById('destination').value;
            window.location = dropDownVal;
        }
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
            <label for="destination">Travelling to:</label>
            <select id="destination" name="destination">
                <option value="https://nstcprep.blogspot.com/">Destination 1</option>
                <option value="https://nstcprep.blogspot.com/">Destination 2</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" onclick="link();">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Let me know if this work.

if you want to open in new tab just change this.

```
window.open(dropDownVal, '_blank');
```